# Why is char '\"' same as char '"'?

Tags: c#, char, special-characters

quick question. Why are both lines below valid?

```
char x = '\"';
char y = '"';
```

If " is a special character, shouldn't the second line be marked as incorrect?

Comment: What could " possibly be in the 2nd case other than in the first?

Comment: C# doesn’t have a concept of “special character”.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> If " is a special character, shouldn't the second line be marked as incorrect?

No, because the rules of the language don't require `"` to be escaped within a character literal, only within a string literal.

It's consistent to *allow* it to be escaped either way, however. That way there's one set of escape sequences which applies to both character and string literals, although `\U........` will fail for any code point which isn't represented by a single UTF-16 code unit.

The difference is within section 2.4.4.5 of the C# spec (string literals) where the *single-regular-string-literal-character* production is:

> Any character except " (U+0022), \ (U+005C), and *new-line-character*

compared with section 2.4.4.4 (character literals) where the *single-character* production is:

> Any character except ' (U+0027), \ (U+005C) and *new-line-character*

As you can see, the opposite of your situation holds for `'`:

```
string x = "'";
string y = "\'";
Console.WriteLine(x == y); // Strings are equivalent
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need escape sequence when the pure value would be ambigious. Escape Sequence are a way of saying: Compiler, ignore that one for the purposes of Syntax udnerstanding. Take it as the pure Value.

```
String s = """; //It would be unclear for the Compiler where the String ends and what is part of it. Hence Escape Sequencs are needed
char c = '"'; //It is clear where the Char starts and ends (the single Quotes). 
char c = '''; //again unclear what of those is the Char. Escape Sequence needed.
```